# Getting "Error validating access token" from Facebook for some users

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-oauth, facebook-permissions, facebook-stream-story

I'm getting the following error from Facebook when trying to post to a users stream.

`Error validating access token: The session has been invalidated because the user has changed the password or because auth.expireSession was called.`

The workflow is as follows:

1. Authorize with Facebook requesting `scope=offline_access,publish_stream` permissions (if the current user has not already authorized)
2. Do some work on the server (takes 5-10 minutes)
3. Attempt to publish to the user's Facebook stream

This code works for many users, but for some users, I get the `Error validating access token` error. It started frequently happening a few weeks ago, then seemed to stop, and now happen a lot again. I'm certainly not calling `auth.expireSession` on my end, and it seems unlikely that multiple users would be changing their password in the 5-10 minute window from authorizing to publishing. Does anyone know what might be causing this?

Comment: I'm not sure, but it maybe that the user "removed" the publish stream permission from your App? also it's always a good idea to update your `access_token` even if it's taken with `offline_access`.

Comment: Are you monitoring the Deauthorize Callback to see if users are uninstalling?

Comment: @Jason I'm not monitoring, but it seems unlikely that a user would grant my app access, then deny access within the next 5-10 minutes. It seems even more unlikely that lots of users would do the same thing within a few day period. Either way, the issue seems to have gone away so I'm guessing it was a temporary FB bug.

Answer (score 8):

Anytime you get this error, you should run the user back through the auth flow.  There are many reasons that either the user or we will invalidate a session.  We have a how-to on this at https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/500

Comment: Thanks for the response. This actually stopped happening a few days after it started. However, re-authing the user wouldn't work in this case since the publishing is happening as part of a background process.

Comment: your app still needs to take this scenario into account.  you can send the user an email, whatever to run them through the auth flow again.

Comment: Link given you is not available.