# Facebook_Graph_Toolkit

Tags: asp.net, facebook-graph-api

I am using Facebook_Graph_Toolkit.dll in my asp.net application. For last few days this was working fine, but now i am getting error "Invalid Access Token". Anyone has idea about this? 
Also please provide me tested and working dll for Facebook API implementation in ASP.NET.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you having similar problem like [Facebook access token invalid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6248173/facebook-access-token-invalid-with-message-session-does-not-match-current-stored) ?
Any way think this might help you [Using ASP.Net with Facebook’s Graph API and OAuth 2.0 Authentication](http://osnapz.wordpress.com/2010/04/23/using-asp-net-with-facebooks-graph-api-and-oauth-2-0-authentication/)

Comment: How can i add extended permission in this?

Comment: http://facebook.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Authentication%20and%20Extended%20Permissions

Comment: You are providing me scatter links. I just followed "Using ASP.Net with Facebook’s Graph API and OAuth 2.0 Authentication" and i am asking for the same code.:(