# Not able to post to Facebook pages because of invalidate token

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, publishing

I am getting error while posting to facebook pages "Error invalidating access token: Session does not match current stored session." I havent changed the pwd too.

I have deleted the app from my facebook account and then reinstalled it , but still the same message. One wierd thing is that i am able to post on my wall , but not on pages.

Is anyone facing this problem too ?

Comment: have you `offline_access` permission?

Comment: yes i have offline_access permission. I have disabled the remove offline_access permission from app settings.

Comment: Read here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6248173/facebook-access-token-invalid-with-message-session-does-not-match-current-store

Answer (score 1):

I think there are some issues with pages and access tokens - I reported the bug - http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/368315619896504 - if you are working with more than one page (or developing), going through the process will invalidate any other page tokens from the same application.

Answer (score 0):

Your token should habe the permissions manage_pages and publish_stream.
Then you have to query the page token using userid/accounts.

There you get a list of pages where the user has posts rights.

to post on a page you should use the token you get from the accounts path.

Comment: i am getting list of pages throught the /accounts api, but that token isnt working too. Is there any changes facebook has done ?